# How to return specific table from page using Ajax reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table on my page with 2 views (simple and collapsible) that I would like to toggle between, via button click, without having to reload the page. Here's my code:

```
    $('#toggle_view').click(function() {

        $.get(window.location.href.replace('&collapsible=true', '&collapsible=false'), function(data) {

            document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = data;

        });
    });
```

However, this returns the entire page contents into my table (understandable). I was wondering how I could specify my code to target and return only the myTable contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#toggle_view').click(function() {
  $.get(window.location.href.replace('&collapsible=true', '&collapsible=false'), function(data) {
      document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = $(data).find('#myTable');
  });
});
```

Thats the answer - u can find by jQuery selector in ur data

Comment: Thanks, I had to add .html(); after the find function, as I was only gettiing back the Object of my table... The successful code is: document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = $(data).find('#myTable').html();

Comment: but why you dont use jQuery?! $('#myTable').html( $(data).find('#myTable').html() );

Comment: I really didnt like when people use jQuery and pure js in one row)